# How to find URL correlated to PEM file

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have a poorly named PEM file and I'm not sure if it's even relevant anymore.

For a given PEM file, is it possible to see what the associated URL is?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can check the Fingerprint and see what server it is on.